# I can't correctly specify the width and height of an image

Tags: html, css, image

I set the width and the height of this image using the code:

```
<img src="assets/desktop/image-phone-and-keyboard.jpg" alt="image-phone-and-keyboard" width="370" height="720">
```

and

```
<img src="assets/desktop/image-glass-and-keyboard.jpg" alt="image-glass-and-keyboard" width="670" heigth="720">
```

[image]

However, when using a digital rule, it gives me other dimensions:

[image]

So I don't understand why I have those dimensions, since I'm using this [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to set the margin:0 and padding:0 applied to images.

My entire code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="reset" href="./CSS/reset.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/styles.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



<title>Frontend Mentor | Typemaster pre-launch landing page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <section class="middle">
        <div class="middle-left">

            <div class="image-phone-and-keyboard">
                <img src="assets/desktop/image-phone-and-keyboard.jpg" alt="image-phone-and-keyboard" width="370" height="720">
            </div>
            <div class="image-glass-and-keyboard">
                <img src="assets/desktop/image-glass-and-keyboard.jpg" alt="image-glass-and-keyboard" width="670" heigth="720">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </main>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1440px;
}

img {
border-radius: 5%;
}

.middle {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.middle-left {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 1080px;
}
```

Comment: Don't you perhaps have any other parent elements pushing the element smaller?

Comment: @JanesOosthuizen In fact I can change the size freely, the only problem is the         number pixels I coded and the true size of the picture don't match

Comment: provide your images and we can find some solution.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but this is most likely a bug in the ruler as a result of not correctly dissolving the ppi of the display. Which ruler are u using?

Comment: @sravanTG the images: https://imgur.com/a/xQIOZSM

Comment: @QuentinAlbert https://apps.apple.com/us/app/measurist/id1423823777?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in html file give the value of width and height attribute for each img element in px.
secondly in css file for * element do this

```
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and there were lot of mistakes in your code. I had to correct them all manually one by one. the starting and ending tags in your html code does not tally together. I don`t know why there is a /main tag in the ending when there is no starting tag named main.

And why there are so many div for containing images. i have made everything concise  and refined everything. since you gave me only one image, i had to take it for both image div.

finally i measured it with ruler and everything was good.
i am giving the html and CSS code below and change the image URL according to you and check it again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="reset" href="./CSS/reset.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Typemaster pre-launch landing page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="phone">
            <img id="image1" class="images" src="img/keyboard.jpeg" alt="image-phone-and-keyboard">
        </div>
        <div class="glass">
            <img id="image2" class="images" src="img/keyboard.jpeg" alt="image-glass-and-keyboard">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#image1 {
  width: 370px;
  height: 720px;
}

#image2 {
  width: 670px;
  height: 720px;
}

.images {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

check this code in a new folder to get an idea of what changes i made.
check it first without including any other code.
don`t forget to set the image urls.

don`t make any changes in css.

Comment: make a new folder for index.html and style.css. link both of them.

Comment: and then paste my html and css in them.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working in Firefox but in Chrome the size isn't the same, Any idea why this is happening?